# VB.NET Iterating Form Labels

Tags: vb.net, forms, loops, iterator

I have several label boxes on my design form that all share the naming convention `lbl_#.text` where # ranges from 1 to 60.  I want to make a loop that iterates through each `lbl_#.text` adding some incremental value, let's say multiples of 2 for this question's theoretical purpose.

Something such that the end result would amount to the following:

```
lbl_1.text = "2"
lbl_2.text = "4"
lbl_3.text = "6"
...
lbl_60.text = "120"
```

I'm not sure how to access each of these labels through the coding side, I only know how to explicitly mention each label and assign a value :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Controls collection:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles    MyBase.Load
        Dim i As Integer
       For i = 1 To 3
            Dim myLabel As Label = CType(Me.Controls("lbl_" & i), Label)
            myLabel.Text = ...whatever value you want to put here
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This is a terrible implementation. You are specifying high and low bounds off an assumed range of strong-named labels. Your code would break if label 2 was renamed or missing. It would not account for labels which have been added over time. The proper way is to use a for each loop and iterate through the label objects contained in  [containerObjectName].Controls.OfType(of Label)()

Comment: Why is it 'awful'?  The user has said: 
'I have several label boxes on my design form that all share the naming convention lbl_#.text where # ranges from 1 to 60.'
Show me where it doesn't meet that requirement.

Comment: Anyway, as better answers have come along since I'll quite happily delete this one.  But not because it doesn't do exactly what's asked.

Comment: fair enough, for this exact question. people coming here from google however, as a general rule this isn't the best approach

Comment: Which is a fair comment.  I'll bear that general point in mind in future.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few options here.

- In this situation the labels will often have a common container, such as panel or groupbox control. In that case:

  ```
  Dim formLabels =  myContainerControl.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
  For Each formLabel As Label In formLabels
     '...
  Next formLabel
  ```

  Of course, this mixes logical groups with visual groupings. Those two things don't always align well, so you can also...
- Add them all to a `Label` array (or `List(Of Label)` or any other enumerable):

  ```
  Dim formLabels(60) As Label = {lbl_1, lbl_2, lbl_3 .... }

  For Each formLabel As Label in formLabels
      '...
  Next formLabel
  ```

  But sometimes that's more trouble than it's worth, even if you use a loop to create the collection, and so  you can also
- Use the `.Name` property (in conjunction with a naming convention to identify your desired controls):

  ```
  Dim formLabels = Controls.Where(Function(c) c.Name.StartsWith("lbl_"))
  For Each formLabel As Label In formLabels
      '...
  Next formLabel
  ```
- Some combination of the above (for example, code in the form load event to create a list based on the name property).

Notice the actual `For Each` loop is *exactly the same* in all of those options. No matter what you do, get to the point where you can write a single expression to identify the label control, and then run a simple loop over the expression result.

This points to a final strategy: think in terms of binding to a data source. With a data source, your labels are created as part of a `DataGridView`, `FlowLayoutPanel`, or similar control. Then you can iterate the rows in the grid or panel.

Comment: This is a great answer! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how many labels there are, one option is to use a Do Loop.

```
    Dim lblTarget As Label = Nothing
    Dim intCursor As Integer = 1
    Dim bolFirstIteration As Boolean = True

    Do Until lblTarget Is Nothing AndAlso Not bolFirstIteration

        If bolFirstIteration Then

            bolFirstIteration = False

        End If

        lblTarget = CType(Me.Controls("lbl_" & intCursor.ToString()), Label)

        If Not lblTarget Is Nothing Then

            lblTarget.Text = (intCursor * 2).ToString()

        End If

        intCursor += 1

    Loop
```