# Use "text" & variable as object name | VB

Tags: variables, for-loop

I have a number of labels (lblSL1, lblSL2, lblSL3, etc)  I wanted to create a for loop where I can simply have "lblSL" & i to insert text into each of these labels with a click of a button.

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To AssetLife
        Me.Controls("lblSL" & i.ToString).Text = SLperYear
    Next
```

Each label will have the value of variable SLperYear, up to however many years AssetLife equals.  I've been trying for many hours with many different code attempts but have had no luck.  Can anyone give me an idea of how to do this?

Comment: see if this helps... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880003/vb-net-iterating-form-labels